# How to Retrieve Data From Web Page Programatically?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

There is a website which shows history of lottery numbers. I want to retrieve numbers from the page, by using C# Windows or Web program(ASP.NET).

There is a problem that, after selecting the week which you want numbers for from dropdownlist, page does not post. Numbers are retrieved by Ajax.

How can I get numbers for all of the weeks by program?

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't any official API provided You should be aware of possible legal issues.

O.K. I understood You know what You are doing, so this is my hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

Comment: Yep - definetely be aware of legal issues.

On my last project, my client's website was being screen scraped by a competitor.

My client then sued the competitor for huge amount of $$$

Answer (score 0):

I've used [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) to interact with Ajax websites and scrape the relevant data before.

Another option is to monitor the site with something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and determine whether you can make the relevant server call directly.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to imitate the ajax requests. you can use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=VS.71).aspx) Class for that